# How can I stop others from posting comments to my post and "like" my post?

Tags: facebook, comments

How can I stop others from posting comments on my post and like my post?

Comment: Post this question in http://webapps.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: You can get help from Facebook for user / account / site problems at https://www.facebook.com/help/?page=220217228006012 - this is not the correct forum for those questions (see http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/faq#questions  for more information)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the facebook graph API to periodically poll your post, enumerate the comments, and delete them.  You can't keep people from liking your posts.

Somehow I don't think this is the answer you're looking for.